# HTML/CSS image rotate and multi spin and ease out

Tags: javascript, css, html

I tried so many CSS code snippets, but all do only parts of what I want.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve within `function myspin(x){}`

1.) on click rotate image x degrees invisibly
2.) and then animate spin 800 degrees visible
 
3.) stop with slow ease out
4.) clear all necessary so on next click on button works again

```js
function myspin() {
  var x = 800;
  document.getElementById("arrowid2").style.transform = "rotate(" + x + "deg)";
  document.getElementById("arrowid2").style.animation = "arrowspin 2s ease-out 1 normal";
}
```

```css
#arrowid2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000">
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="myspin();" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <img id="arrowid2" src="arrow001.png" alt="" border="0" width="87" height="306">
</body>
```

Comment: Where is the code in which you've tried any of the above?

Comment: I tried to take this and modify it http://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/1906/

Comment: stackoverflow complains I have only code and reject it. http://jim289.bplaced.de/1234uurzz/bla.txt

Comment: http://jim289.bplaced.de/1234uurzz/index1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all rotation is done in css, js only adds/removes `animated` class after 2500ms(animation duration). why do you want 800 deg? it will jump in that case to existing position, I made 360*3 instead as of now so animation ends where it starts

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('animated');
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(that).removeClass('animated');
  }, 2500)
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 135px;
}
img.animated {
  animation: spin ease-out 2.5s;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  10%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1080deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='https://puu.sh/tTsnZ/9294a8c88e.png' />
```

Comment: 800 ° is example only. Important is few times 360 ° and a bit more animated spin.

Comment: @hugo289 what do you mean by 'more animated spin'? extra duration?

Comment: A random number not exactly multiple of 360 °. At least 2 * 360 + and a bit. you know ? ;-)

Comment: @hugo289 so put your random number instead `1080deg` I'm not getting your question

Comment: "animate spin 800 degrees"  means see image rotating not just jump to 800 °

Comment: @hugo289 which browser do you use?

Comment: @hugo289 and actually it _does_ rotate

Comment: Your answer is good, but not exactly what I want because I give confusing explanation. http://jim289.bplaced.de/1234uurzz/index1.html  Do you know how to make it that at every click arrow spinning multiple time arround and then go to random number. And at every click stoping smoothly.

Comment: @hugo289 you need to post a new question then. this one is answered and new answer will be incosistent here